# Re-ordering sections in a free wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Whenever I try to place this code in the child theme, it always gives me this error. 
[Rollback error(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc6pR.png)

Comment: so change the function name?

Comment: I've changed the function name in the child theme before, and it didn't change anything or at times it doesn't load the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the function in your parent theme pluggable.

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists ( 'my_function' ) ) {
function my_function() {
    // Contents of your function here.
}
}
?>
```

That way if the same function exists in the child, it is skipped. However if you do not want to change the parent theme at all, there are other options. Please let me know and I will post them however this option is the simplist.

Comment: Great! Happy to help